# How to launch dynamic url Link in cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to launch the child window tab which is having dynamic link in the application, link is as below:

```js
http://localhost:8080/#/investigation/1141131893/popupwindow/567875854/searchinstancefilter
```

In this link: 1141131893 -->>this number gets changed everytime when we open the case, also its search instance number : 567875854 --get changed everytime. So I am not able to visit the link and launch the child window due to these dynamic attributes. Please help me for the cypress code. This I am doing in cypress Automation, and I want the code of it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for this:

```js
const investigationNum = '475357353'
const searchInstanceNum = '357834656'
cy.visit(`http://localhost:8080/#/investigation/${investigationNum}/popupwindow/${searchInstanceNum}/searchinstancefilter`)
```